# C# iTextSharp to manipulate tagged pdf structure

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tagged-pdf

I want to manipulate (modify) a fully tagged pdf. Using below code i am able to get the document tree structure

```
PdfDictionary catalog = reader.Catalog;
PdfDictionary struc = catalog.GetAsDict(PdfName.STRUCTTREEROOT);
```

now I want to modify the below structure

[Incorrect tagging structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNfpo.png)

want to remove  tag which is inside the  tag, and also move the content from  to

to

[Correct tagging structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8p4w.png)

Please guide me, I have little bit knowledge of coding.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @mkl request you please solve this.